# Android Studio AVD Manager greyed out

Tags: android-studio

I am not sure why this is but when I open up my project in Android Studio 2.1.2 and try to click the AVD manager to install and create an emulator, I can't click the AVD icon.

[image]

Comment: In my case I had to fix my Gradle build before it would enable the AVD Manager button.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out I needed

Intel X86 Atom System Image

and Google APIs, for the AVD button to be clickable.